# Is there a way that I can synchronize MySQL server and SQlite in Ionic 2?

Tags: mysql, sqlite, ionic2

I want to synchronize MySQL server database to a local sqlite database in ionic 2 in order to enable users store information offline then call/send changes when online.

I have seen a few ways to make it work in android but i haven't found much information about it in ionic 2.

Comment: I am looking for the same. most of tutorials suggest couchdb so if you got the solution help by answering the question yourself

Answer (score 0):

We assume that you have installed Node.js and able to run `npm` in Node.js command line (Windows) or Terminal (OS X/Linux). To make sure everything is up to date, type this command in the terminal or Node command line.

```
npm install -g ionic cordova
```

To add Ionic 3 Native SQLite and Toast plugin, just type this commands.

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-sqlite-storage
npm install --save @ionic-native/sqlite
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-x-toast
npm install --save @ionic-native/toast
```

Now, open and edit `src/app/app.module.ts` then add this imports.

```
import { SQLite } from '@ionic-native/sqlite';
import { Toast } from '@ionic-native/toast';
```

Add `SQLite` and `Toast` to `@NgModule` providers, so it will look like this.

```
providers: [
  StatusBar,
  SplashScreen,
  {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},
  SQLite,
  Toast
]
```

The implementation of CRUD mobile app with Ionic 3, Angular 4 and SQLite start by creating a list of expense. For that, open and edit default `src/pages/home/home.ts` then add this imports.

```
import { SQLite, SQLiteObject } from '@ionic-native/sqlite';
import { AddDataPage } from '../add-data/add-data';
import { EditDataPage } from '../edit-data/edit-data';
```

Two imports of Add and Edit data required new pages for add and edit data that will be added later. Now, inject `SQLite` on the constructor variable.

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
  private sqlite: SQLite) {}
```

Add this variable for array of expenses, total income, total expense and balance before the constructor.

```
expenses: any = [];
totalIncome = 0;
totalExpense = 0;
balance = 0;
```

Add this functions below the constructor for the complete CRUD.

```
ionViewDidLoad() {
  this.getData();
}

ionViewWillEnter() {
  this.getData();
}

getData() {
  this.sqlite.create({
    name: 'ionicdb.db',
    location: 'default'
  }).then((db: SQLiteObject) => {
    db.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS expense(rowid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, date TEXT, type TEXT, description TEXT, amount INT)', {})
    .then(res => console.log('Executed SQL'))
    .catch(e => console.log(e));
    db.executeSql('SELECT * FROM expense ORDER BY rowid DESC', {})
    .then(res => {
      this.expenses = [];
      for(var i=0; i<res.rows.length; i++) {
        this.expenses.push({rowid:res.rows.item(i).rowid,date:res.rows.item(i).date,type:res.rows.item(i).type,description:res.rows.item(i).description,amount:res.rows.item(i).amount})
      }
    })
    .catch(e => console.log(e));
    db.executeSql('SELECT SUM(amount) AS totalIncome FROM expense WHERE type="Income"', {})
    .then(res => {
      if(res.rows.length>0) {
        this.totalIncome = parseInt(res.rows.item(0).totalIncome);
        this.balance = this.totalIncome-this.totalExpense;
      }
    })
    .catch(e => console.log(e));
    db.executeSql('SELECT SUM(amount) AS totalExpense FROM expense WHERE type="Expense"', {})
    .then(res => {
      if(res.rows.length>0) {
        this.totalExpense = parseInt(res.rows.item(0).totalExpense);
        this.balance = this.totalIncome-this.totalExpense;
      }
    })
  }).catch(e => console.log(e));
}

addData() {
  this.navCtrl.push(AddDataPage);
}

editData(rowid) {
  this.navCtrl.push(EditDataPage, {
    rowid:rowid
  });
}

deleteData(rowid) {
  this.sqlite.create({
    name: 'ionicdb.db',
    location: 'default'
  }).then((db: SQLiteObject) => {
    db.executeSql('DELETE FROM expense WHERE rowid=?', [rowid])
    .then(res => {
      console.log(res);
      this.getData();
    })
    .catch(e => console.log(e));
  }).catch(e => console.log(e));
}
```

Next, open and edit `src/pages/home/home.html` then replace all code with this.

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>
      My Expense
    </ion-title>
    <ion-buttons end>
      <button ion-button icon-only (click)="addData()">
        <ion-icon name="add-circle"></ion-icon>
      </button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <h2>Expense List</h2>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let expense of expenses; let i=index">
      <ion-item nopadding>
        <p>
          <span>{{expense.date}}</span><br>
          Type: {{expense.type}}<br>
          {{expense.description}}
        </p>
        <h3 item-end>
          Amount: ${{expense.amount}}
        </h3>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item-options side="right">
        <button ion-button color="primary" (click)="editData(expense.rowid)">
          <ion-icon name="paper"></ion-icon>
        </button>
        <button ion-button color="danger" (click)="deleteData(expense.rowid)">
          <ion-icon name="trash"></ion-icon>
        </button>
      </ion-item-options>
    </ion-item-sliding>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
<ion-footer>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>Balance: ${{balance}}</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-footer>
```

Type this command for creating a new page for adding new data.

```
ionic g page AddData
```

Open and edit `src/pages/add-data/add-data.ts` then replace all codes with this.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { SQLite, SQLiteObject } from '@ionic-native/sqlite';
import { Toast } from '@ionic-native/toast';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-add-data',
  templateUrl: 'add-data.html',
})
export class AddDataPage {

  data = { date:"", type:"", description:"", amount:0 };

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
    public navParams: NavParams,
    private sqlite: SQLite,
    private toast: Toast) {}

  saveData() {
    this.sqlite.create({
      name: 'ionicdb.db',
      location: 'default'
    }).then((db: SQLiteObject) => {
      db.executeSql('INSERT INTO expense VALUES(NULL,?,?,?,?)',[this.data.date,this.data.type,this.data.description,this.data.amount])
        .then(res => {
          console.log(res);
          this.toast.show('Data saved', '5000', 'center').subscribe(
            toast => {
              this.navCtrl.popToRoot();
            }
          );
        })
        .catch(e => {
          console.log(e);
          this.toast.show(e, '5000', 'center').subscribe(
            toast => {
              console.log(toast);
            }
          );
        });
    }).catch(e => {
      console.log(e);
      this.toast.show(e, '5000', 'center').subscribe(
        toast => {
          console.log(toast);
        }
      );
    });
  }

}
```

Next, open and edit `src/pages/add-data/add-data.html` then replace all codes with this.

```
<ion-header>

  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>My Expense</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <h2>Add Data</h2>
  <form (ngSubmit)="saveData()">
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Date</ion-label>
      <ion-datetime displayFormat="MM/DD/YYYY" [(ngModel)]="data.date" name="date" required=""></ion-datetime>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Type</ion-label>
      <ion-select [(ngModel)]="data.type" name="type" required="">
        <ion-option value="Income">Income</ion-option>
        <ion-option value="Expense">Expense</ion-option>
      </ion-select>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Description</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="text" placeholder="Description" [(ngModel)]="data.description" name="description" required="" ></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Amount</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="number" placeholder="Amount" [(ngModel)]="data.amount" name="amount" required="" ></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <button ion-button type="submit" block>Save Data</button>
  </form>
</ion-content>
```

Type this command for creating a new page for edit data.

```
ionic g page EditData
```

Open and edit `src/pages/edit-data/edit-data.ts` then replace all codes with this.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { SQLite, SQLiteObject } from '@ionic-native/sqlite';
import { Toast } from '@ionic-native/toast';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-edit-data',
  templateUrl: 'edit-data.html',
})
export class EditDataPage {

  data = { rowid:0, date:"", type:"", description:"", amount:0 };

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
    public navParams: NavParams,
    private sqlite: SQLite,
    private toast: Toast) {
      this.getCurrentData(navParams.get("rowid"));
  }

  getCurrentData(rowid) {
    this.sqlite.create({
      name: 'ionicdb.db',
      location: 'default'
    }).then((db: SQLiteObject) => {
      db.executeSql('SELECT * FROM expense WHERE rowid=?', [rowid])
        .then(res => {
          if(res.rows.length > 0) {
            this.data.rowid = res.rows.item(0).rowid;
            this.data.date = res.rows.item(0).date;
            this.data.type = res.rows.item(0).type;
            this.data.description = res.rows.item(0).description;
            this.data.amount = res.rows.item(0).amount;
          }
        })
        .catch(e => {
          console.log(e);
          this.toast.show(e, '5000', 'center').subscribe(
            toast => {
              console.log(toast);
            }
          );
        });
    }).catch(e => {
      console.log(e);
      this.toast.show(e, '5000', 'center').subscribe(
        toast => {
          console.log(toast);
        }
      );
    });
  }

  updateData() {
    this.sqlite.create({
      name: 'ionicdb.db',
      location: 'default'
    }).then((db: SQLiteObject) => {
      db.executeSql('UPDATE expense SET date=?,type=?,description=?,amount=? WHERE rowid=?',[this.data.date,this.data.type,this.data.description,this.data.amount,this.data.rowid])
        .then(res => {
          console.log(res);
          this.toast.show('Data updated', '5000', 'center').subscribe(
            toast => {
              this.navCtrl.popToRoot();
            }
          );
        })
        .catch(e => {
          console.log(e);
          this.toast.show(e, '5000', 'center').subscribe(
            toast => {
              console.log(toast);
            }
          );
        });
    }).catch(e => {
      console.log(e);
      this.toast.show(e, '5000', 'center').subscribe(
        toast => {
          console.log(toast);
        }
      );
    });
  }

}
```

Next, open and edit `src/pages/edit-data/edit-data.html` then replace all codes with this.

```
<ion-header>

  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>My Expense</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <h2>Edit Data</h2>
  <form (ngSubmit)="updateData()">
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Date</ion-label>
      <ion-datetime displayFormat="MM/DD/YYYY" [(ngModel)]="data.date" name="date" required=""></ion-datetime>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Type</ion-label>
      <ion-select [(ngModel)]="data.type" name="type" required="">
        <ion-option value="Income">Income</ion-option>
        <ion-option value="Expense">Expense</ion-option>
      </ion-select>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Description</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="text" placeholder="Description" [(ngModel)]="data.description" name="description" required="" ></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Amount</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="number" placeholder="Amount" [(ngModel)]="data.amount" name="amount" required="" ></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-input type="hidden" [(ngModel)]="data.rowid" name="rowid"></ion-input>
    <button ion-button type="submit" block>Update Data</button>
  </form>
</ion-content>
```

Before running the Ionic 3, Angular 4 and SQLite app on the device, remove and add the platforms first.

```
ionic cordova platform rm android
ionic cordova platform rm ios
ionic cordova platform add android
ionic cordova platform add ios
```

Now, run the app after back to the current folder.

for ios

```
ionic cordova run ios
```

For Android should be the same as iOS except for UI behavior. You can run by type this command.

```
ionic cordova run android
```

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all you need to read all your data as the app launches. Make a service that returns all the table with records that you need when the app is offline. Let it run on the background.
2. When the read is complete, import it to your local SqLite. I prefer to use https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/sqlite-porter/ though you have to restructure the returning JSON.
3. Now when the app goes offline, anytime you make a request, you have to read it locally from the SqLite.
4. When you insert,update or delete a data, add a column like a flag for each record, that this record has been modified,added, or deleted.
5. When the app goes online, read all the modified records and send back to the server.